# Which is the way to use OAuth on an android app against a server?

Tags: android, ios, oauth

I've recently done some OAuth authentications on Android apps (or iOS), but I now have a problem.

When this OAuth authentication needs to be stored in a remote server to perform login request. Which is the best way to do this?

Should I send access token from this oauth provider, and then get otherr access_token just for my app?

Or should it be done in a different way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's no general answer but I'll try to explain.

2 basic flows I can think of :

1) If yo don't want that your app directly asks for a username/password, you can use Facebook/Twitter login.

2) Ask the user for a username/password directly and implement your own OAuth service with your server, then use an iOS OAuth library to communicate with it. Your service will need to perform user/pass authentication at some stage.
You can either generate a random UID (user identification) on the client and use that to communicate to the server. Or you can just pass the username/password, let the server generate a UID and from there on communicate using that UID in the request headers.

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks, but If I'm making oauth with facebook and facebook the way to go will be to send access token to server and retrive an access_token generated from my server?

Comment: Well you can do that or you can just pass around the facebook access token and you'll not be needing a server generated token

Comment: When you first pass the access token, and the server creates a new account, the server should associate that account from the facebook id of that user (which can be retrieved from the token.). So even when the token changes, the facebook id will not, and can be used to uniquely identify the user.